# Spring Security Custom Filter (Change Password)

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security for securing HTTP requests to a website. The primary usage is for securing pages such that the user is redirected to the login page when trying to access those pages.

However, I have a further requirement. In my model, I can flag a user's password as being temporary such that, when they successfully login, they should be automatically forced to change their password. Once the password is changed, they should then be forwarded on to the page they were originally trying to access.

Has anyone used Spring Security for this purpose? Do I need to create my own custom filter?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Spring Security 3.0 you can implement a custom [`AuthenticationSuccessHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html).

In this handler you can redirect a user with temporary password to the password change page instead of the originally requested page. After password is changed, you may redirect user to the originally requested page using `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, which is the default handler implementation.

```
public class MyHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler target = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();

    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) {
        if (hasTemporaryPassword(auth)) {
            response.sendRedirect("/changePassword");
        } else {
            target.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, auth);
        }
    }

    public void proceed(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) {
        target.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, auth);
    }
}

@Controller("/changePassword")
public class ChangePasswordController {

    @Autowired
    private MyHandler handler;

    @RequestMapping(method = POST)
    public void changePassword(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(name = "newPassword") String newPassword) {

        // handle password change
        ...

        // proceed to the secured page
        handler.proceed(request, response, auth);        
    }

    // form display method, etc
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I can do the first part pretty easily but not sure what you mean by "redirect user to...using SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler". How do I redirect to a handler?

Comment: @dewzilla: I added the sample of how it might look like (with Spring MVC controller for password change, not tested).

Comment: Actually it is counterintuitive to check for password expiration in authentication success handler, isn't it? You shouldn't be able to authenticate if password is expired. Check answer provided by @jyore.

Comment: Answer would have been better if configuration was also included. For this to work, additional security-app-context.xml configuration is needed. i.e., [http://pastebin.com/pxe5byaF].

Comment: This solution has the drawback that user can freely continue to other page of the application after being redirected to changePassword page and never actually change his/her password. He is in the end successfully authenticated and nothing prevents him from doing so.

Comment: Sorry, downvoted that one because using this technique is very insecure, as Ondrej pointed out.  A user could walk around the password reset requirement.

Answer (score 14):

A little late on this, but hopefully this can help others finding this link.  If you use a custom UserDetailsService, you can set the User object's credentialsNonExpired to false, for example, to not allow access to any secure content until that field is set back to true.

Basically, when you have password expiration, you will set a field in your User model (passwordExpired maybe), and when your UserDetailsService pulls the user, your UserDetailsService will use that value to set credentialsNonExpired.

Then, all you need to do is add some config to your applicationContext-security.xml to setup authentication exception mappings.  This will allow you to catch the exception thrown with expired credentials and force the user to a reset password page. You can additionally catch locked and disabled accounts using a similar method. The config example is shown below:

**applicationContext-security.xml**

```
<beans:bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
        <beans:props>           
            <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException">/login_error</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException">/password_expired</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException">/locked</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="org.springframework.secuirty.authentication.DisabledException">/disabled</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<http use-expressions="true">
    <!-- ADD BLACKLIST/WHITELIST URL MAPPING -->
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-handler-ref="exceptionTranslationFilter" />
</http>
```

Then just make sure you have your controllers setup to serve those links with the appropriate content.

Comment: This solution has a drawback that user credentialsNonExpired is checked before user is authenticated thus you reveal that a user credentials are expired to a non-authenticated user (e.g. attacker). I guess such a piece of information is not that critical but I still find rodrigoap solution with filter better.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, I did this with a filter ForceChangePasswordFilter. Because if the user types the url by hand they can bypass the change password form. With the filter the request always get intercepted.

Comment: Jonathan, that was many years ago, I do not have access to that code now.

Comment: rodrigoap I understand. I share the same sentiment that if you use the success handler, user will still be able to access other pages by writing the url directly at the address bar. But basically, could you share at least the intent inside the filter? I tried having a redirect inside the Filter and it causes an infinite redirect loop as what is mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954930/spring-security-3-0-how-do-i-specify-urls-to-which-a-custom-filter-applies. Will just post a separate question for this in SO.

Comment: I posted a separate question for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848757/how-to-enforce-change-password-on-users-initial-login-using-spring-security). Would you mind posting your reply there?

Comment: I think that this is the best answer as it let's user authenticate first and then does not allow him to go anywhere else but to change his password. Is there a way to ask original questioner to change the correct answer here? @Jonathan also provided detailed description with code samples how to do it in his next question.

Comment: Can't this be mitigated by only giving the user access to the change password form and updating the authorities after a successful password change? You could even force another logout/login. Lots of sites do this but I find it a bit unfriendly to the user.

Comment: Tutorial for how to add a security filter: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter

Answer (score 3):

Very useful answer form [jyore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/833820/jyore), it was exactly what I was looking for. In case you are using a custom class implementing `UserDetailsService`, you can do it as the following along with the above bean definition in your `applicationContext.xml`. One thing is that based on your CML header you might need to use `<bean ....` or `<prop ...` instead of  `<beans:bean ...` or `<beans:prop ...`

```
import ......

@Service("userService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(UserDetailsServiceImpl.class);

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername( String username )
    throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException , CredentialsExpiredException ,BadCredentialsException ,
    LockedException , DisabledException , UsernameNotFoundException
{
    User user = userDao.getUserByUsername( username );
    System.out.println("User Found");

    if( user == null ){
        // System.out.println("User Not Found");
        logger.error( "User Not Found");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException( username + " is not found." );
    }

    if( user.isEnabled() == false ){
    // System.out.println("User not enabled");
    logger.error( "User not enabled");
       throw new DisabledException( "User not enabled" );
   }

    if( user.isLocked() == true ){
         //System.out.println("User is Locked");
        logger.error( "User is Locked");
          throw new LockedException( "User is Locked" );
      }
    if( user.isPasswordExpired() == true ){
        // System.out.println("Password Expired");
        logger.error( "Password Expired");
         throw new CredentialsExpiredException( "Password Expired" );
     }  

    return user;
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the UserDetailsService is called before the password is checked.