# Spring Security 3.0: How do I specify URLs to which a custom filter applies?

Tags: servlets, spring-security, servlet-filters

I am using Spring Security 3.0 with JSPs.  I have created a RequireVerificationFilter that redirects unverified users to a "verify your email" page.

I added the filter to the spring security filter stack in last place like so:

Bean definition in my app-config.xml:

```
<bean id="requireVerificationFilter" class="com.ebisent.web.RequireVerificationFilter" />
```

Filter added to spring security filter list in my security-config.xml:

```
<custom-filter ref="requireVerificationFilter" after="LAST" />
```

The filter works, but it filters its own redirect URL.  That is, the filter redirects unverified users to /access/verify, but that URL is also caught by the filter, which attempts the redirect ad infinitum.

I tried using the `<filter-mapping>` tag to restrict the URLs this new filter applies to, but that does not seem to work the way I thought it would.  Here is the web.xml entry I added anyway:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>requireVerificationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.ebisent.web.RequireVerificationFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>requireVerificationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/account/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I read through "Adding in Your Own Filters" in the spring security documention, but did not find an answer.

My question is, How can I specify which URLs my filter applies to?

**UPDATE:**

I got this working by specifying the URL to allow within the filter itself.  This works fine for me, but if there is a better/more "springy" way to do it, I would be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this inside the actual configuration xml (same place you have the `<custom-filter ref="requireVerificationFilter" after="LAST" />` .

```
<http ...>
   <intercept-url pattern="/access" ... filters="..., requireVerificationFilter, ..." />
   <intercept-url pattern="/verify" ... filters="none" />
   ...
</http>
```

Something along those lines, you can specify a list of the filters you want to run and exclude those you don't (and "none" means none).  You should not need to add tyour filter to the web.xml - only inline with the Spring Security filter chain.

Comment: Thank you!  I have intercept-url tags in my security config, but I didn't know you could specify filters there.

Comment: But [Spring Security Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-intercept-url-parents) says that : `filters` attribute "Can only take the value “none”".

Answer (score 4):

You should use `org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy` for this. the attribute filter should only containts `none`:

```
<http ...>
      <custom-filter ref="requireVerificationFilterChain" after="LAST" />
</http>

<b:bean id="requireVerificationFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
            <filter-chain pattern="/account/*" filters="requireVerificationFilter"/>
        </filter-chain-map>
</b:bean>
<b:bean id="requireVerificationFilter" class="com.ebisent.web.RequireVerificationFilter" />
```