# Spring security 3 how to do change password

Tags: spring, passwords, spring-security

I used spring security to login option. Now i want to add a change password option.first time user login to the system change password option need to be appear or redirect to change password page.
this is my spring security file

```
<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
            <security:salt-source ref="saltSource"/>
        </security:password-encoder>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="saltSource" class="com.rcfi.lankaweb.linklk.support.service.SaltService"></bean>

<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="com.rcfi.lankaweb.linklk.support.service.PasswordVerifier"></bean>

<bean id="userDetailsService"
    class="com.rcfi.lankaweb.linklk.support.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl">
</bean>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335559/spring-security-custom-filter-change-password

Answer (score 0):

Create a change password method in your `com.rcfi.lankaweb.linklk.support.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl`
this will take the new String and save to database for the logged in user, via your user dao (probably)

Comment: Thanx NimChimpsky, Got idea from you and do the rest.