# AppFuse PassWord Management in struts framework

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-security, struts, appfuse

I got one doubt. In AppFuse during Login some action is to be called to check the credentials.
      In login page there is a action name /j_security-check but I can't find any action class for that action name in struts.xml file.
      Then how its get redirected to mainMenu.

Can someone help me with this thing

thanks and regards
rajNaveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently , Appfuse2 uses Spring Security 3 as the security framework .So form action `j_security-check` is handled by  Spring Security 3 and it is nothing to do with Struts.

The idea is that in the `web.xml` , you will found that a Spring Security 3 configuration file ( `/WEB-INF/security.xml`) which  configures the Security behaviour of the web application will be loaded and processed during the webapp starts up . It is configured  to use `DaoAuthenticationProvider` to do the authentication .

Spring security will intercept `j_security-check` form action and call  `DaoAuthenticationProvider` to process the login request . `DaoAuthenticationProvider` in turns call its `UserDetailsService` , which is implemented by developers ,  to lookup the password for the login user and then simply comparing if the retrieved password matches the submitted password.

I suggest you check out [Spring Security 3](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity.html).

Comment: hi Ken, i saw security.xml file, it has

Comment: hi Ken, i saw security.xml file, it has <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>                                                           UserDao is used in how it compares the credentials from database,  bcoz if i want to add one feature like change password after the password expires(let it be for 10days), I have to perform this during login itself, so if I want add additional features means how it will take that feature and where I have to add it(in which class)

Comment: Sounds like this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335559/spring-security-custom-filter-change-password fits your requirement . In the handler , redirect a user with expiry password to the password change page