# Spring security authorization

Tags: spring, gwt, internationalization, spring-security

At my project I use Spring Security and GWT with url-like internationalization (http://....html?locale=en). Login and logout functions work very well, but here is another hitch: when user login he got localization-like URL (for example http://localhost:8000/Admin/app/Admin.html?locale=en) but after he close window (without logout) and coming back at URL http://localhost:8000/Admin/ he take authorization by Spring Security with session and login at system without "?locale=" param, so he got default language.

The main question is - how can I interrupt between two process (after Spring say - "Ok! it a good user - comin!" and before he throw user a link to coming) so that I can add locale to his URL ?
Thanks.

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335559/spring-security-custom-filter-change-password

Comment: thx, if you will post this link as answer I will marked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` to add parameters to the request on authentication success. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3335886/982084).