# spring security: password change page implementation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to spring and web development at all. I want to implement user password change funcionality. Till now, I have used only paths in this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/timetable/{year}/{month}/{date}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String timetableDateJump(@PathVariable("year") int year, @PathVariable("month") int month..)
```

But I don't want user's pass to be passed just in url. How is it done in web services? What is a normal why to implement that?

btw: of coruse i should pass the password from user tpo server and hash it on the server side, right?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335559/spring-security-custom-filter-change-password

Comment: Yes, i have - in fact it deals with how to FORCE redirection to user page change, not how to implement it

Comment: What more are you looking for? The accepted answer has a method signature which maps to HTTP POST. All you need to do is fill out how to physically change the password, and that's going to depend on the data store where your user ID and passwords are kept.

Comment: I'm also not quite sure how to write jsp page which for example passes user's password from some input form to http request

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view no spring-security specific details here:

1) create form in view

```
<form:form method="post" action="/password/change" modelAttribute="changePasswordForm">
    <form:label path="password">
        New password:
    </form:label>
    <form:password path="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Change password" />
</form:form>
```

2) create class for binding user's values from form to java object

```
public class ChangePasswordForm {
    private String password;

    public void setPassword(String password)
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

3) create controller

```
@Controller
public ChangePasswordController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/password/change", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String changePassword(ChangePasswordForm form) {
        // change user password
        return "return:/user/info";
    }
}
```

I not tested this code but it should work in this fashion.

How to update password in database it depends from your applications and used libraries.