# Spring Security Custom Filter URL mapping is npt working with JdbcDAOImpl

Tags: spring, spring-security

Spring Security.xml:

```
 <!--form login-->
        <form-login login-page="/UserLogin" default-target-url="/XploreHome"
                    authentication-failure-handler-ref="ExceptionTranslationFilter"/>
                <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" />
    <!--Exception filters-->
        <beans:bean id="ExceptionTranslationFilter"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
                <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
                    <beans:props>
                    <beans:prop
                            key="org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException">/UserLogin?x=1</beans:prop>
                        <beans:prop
                            key="org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException">/resetPasswd</beans:prop>
                        <beans:prop
                             key="org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException">/resetPasswd</beans:prop>
                        <beans:prop
                            key="org.springframework.secuirty.authentication.DisabledException">/resetPasswd</beans:prop> 
                    </beans:props>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
<!--JDBC USER service-->
<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select emailAddress,password,active from userdetails where emailAddress=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select ux.emailAddress,ax.authority from userdetails ux,userauthority ax where ux.PK_USER_ID=ax.PK_AUTHORITY_ID and  ux.emailAddress=?" />
```

If the **active** value in the DB column is set to 0 then I get **User is disabled** exception in the browser instead of my **resetPassword** page

resetPassword page is accessible only for authenticated users.

**How My web app works or intended to work:**

When a new user registers I send a temporary password to his email address and set **active** to 0.

When he uses that password to login for the first time I need to force him to change the password but I get this error

`HTTP Status 401 - Authentication Failed: User is disabled`

and I came across this exception from spring docs It says that if user account is disabled it will never authenticate the user and hence I am not able to navigate to **resetPassword** page, So how do I resolve this issue?And force the user to **resetPassword** page.

If this works I can apply this logic to my **forgotPwd** logic too,Where I send a temporary password to user's email address and set **active** to zero.

I hope I make sense in my above explanation!

Comment: rather than forcing user to change password you can send link to user in mail which you are sending after registering the user. when user clicks this link then activate this user bye changing field in users database of spring security.

Comment: But my actual goal is to force the user to reset his password,I have gone through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335559/spring-security-custom-filter-change-password

Comment: Is there any value to active or add a new column to make the user account password expired and force him to reset page?(for eg: when value is 1 for active the account is enabled, 0 disabled).

Comment: as you are forcing user to change password on first login, but to login user its account has to enabled which is false in users table thats why is it giving you error.

Comment: Yes I figured out that one but if it is enabled user will be redirected to home page.so I want something like the password expired when he tries to login so that I can show him reset password page,or any other suggestion?

Comment: You can do one thing send mail something like a href='"+ getCurrentContext(request) +"/pwdRst?uid="+user.getUserId() after user registration , /pwdRst will hit your controller where you can enable users account and then redirect him to password change page

Comment: @Vasudev Pathak :This above suggestion doesn't work as my resetPassword page is accessible only to the authenticated users,even if I enable account on hitting to controller ,Still redirect to resetPassword won't happen until he authenticates himself.